# How can I convert an object to a string (Twig & Symfony)?

Tags: javascript, loops, symfony, datatables, twig

I have a jquery function that is mixed with twig data:

```
$(document).on('change', '.item-select', function() {

var optionValue = $(this).val();
{% for key, value in columns_arr %}
{% for k,v in group %}
if (optionValue == "{{ v.id }}") {
  {% set output = v %}
  {% for method in value|split('.') if method != '' %}
  {% set output = attribute(output, method) | default('') %}
  {% endfor %}
  var {{ value | split('.') | first }} = "{{ output }}";
}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}


if (optionValue) {
  var entity = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-parent');
  var relation = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-slug');
  var uuid= $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-id');


  table.row.add({
    {% for key, value in columns_arr %}
    {% for k,v in group %}
    "{{ value | split('.') | first }}": {{ value | split('.') | first }},
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  }).draw();
  $('option', this).first().prop('selected', true);
  fetch(`/row/${entity}/${relation}/${uuid}/${optionValue}`,{
    method: 'POST'
  }).then(res => window.location.reload());
}

});
```

I get the error message:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   Proxies__CG__\App\Entity\Productgroup could not be converted to
>   string").

And the error should be in this line:

> var {{ value | split('.') | first }} = "{{ output }}";

Comment: Can you give us an idea, what `column_arr` looks like? It seems it is an array of `Productgroup` entities. You should call the specific field of them (`{{ value.name | split('.') | first }}` for example) or give these entities a `__toString` method.

Comment: @Wulf This is clolumns_arr: `array:4 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "productgroup"
  3 => "category.name"
]`

Comment: @Jarla  - What is your expected output? Don't forget you can easily access any property for the object `productgroup` by changing the column definition. e.g `productgroup.name`

Comment: @DarkBee  To demonstrate to you, here are two variations of the arrays. The first variation is working and the second variation getting the error. I need the second variation to work too: https://codeshare.io/5O6mZP

Comment: @DarkBee I think I know what is the problem. In the example code I was sending you I see that colums_arr should be `array:4 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "productgroup.name"
  3 => "category.name"
]
` instead of `array:4 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "productgroup"
  3 => "category.name"
]` I think this is where I need to make the fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try implementing `JsonSerializable` in your Entity to then use its methods `__toString()` and `jsonSerialize` and rewrite them as u want.

https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jsonserializable-interface/

Answer (score 4):

If you give Twig an object, it implicitly calls the __toString() method on that object. That is how you get the error message.

Are you looking for a variable value on that object? In such case, use the field name (e.g. output.something).

What you are apparently trying to do is use the object as an object and handle it with javascript functions. The easiest way to do that is typically to use the json_encode filter, which will produce a JSON object with proper encoding and everything, provided your underlying Symfony/Doctrine object is clean.

```
var {{ value | split('.') | first }} = "{{ output | json_encode }}";
```

should do the trick.

But honestly, I think that style of code is asking for trouble. You should assign your variables explicitly and not iterate over field names the way you seem to be doing.

Comment: Using the quotes around `{{ output | json_encode }}` will leave the output useless in `JS`

Comment: Thank you. The error message is gone with your code. Problem is now, in my datatable I need the following fields `8, fred, animals, products` and with json encode version the fields are `8, "fred", {"__initializer__":null,"__cloner__":null,"__isInitialized__":true},"products",`

Comment: Like I said, this only works if you have a proper object because it doesn't do anything smart, it only converts the object into proper JSON notation. I would strongly suggest that you do explicit assigns, e.g. "var animals = output.animals; var products = ..." - if you have arrays there (as the plural suggests), you may want to use json_encode at that level. If you have objects there... implement the __toString() method.